# Can I use NVIDIA A100 40GB PCIe GPU with a PCIe ver 3 connector?

Tags: gpu, pci-express

Can I use an NVIDIA A100 40GB PCIe GPU on a motherboard with PCIe ver 3 connectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
A100 PCIe is connected to the rest of the system using a PCI-Express 4.0 x16
```

Keywords: using a PCI-Express.

PCI-e is backward compatible. So this will also work with PCI-e v3, PCI-e v2 etc. But performance may be lower.